# how to receive emails on linux?

Tags: centos, email, smtp, pop3, email-server

Is there any small utility to receive emails on linux ? Ideally I would need to point mx records on my server and through just a command read all the emails received. I don't need pop3, imap, any user account management, database etc ... basically just a catch-all email service on linux. Basically if it would write all the emails received to a text file it would be good enough but i don't know how to listen for emails ...

Comment: the question is quite precise ... don't really understand why  Ward, devicenull, Michael Hampton, John Gardeniers, mdpc don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. You would need to configure a MTA (postfix, exim, etc.) with aliases for all the mail accounts you want to receive mail for to a single user, and then invoke a console based e-mail client as the user you're routing the mail to.

I will not recommend a specific MTA or client, as there are several that can do the job and this already risks being interpreted as a [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) question.

Comment: that sounds complicated

Comment: It's not a simple thing, no. MTA servers are used for receiving and processing mail. E-mail clients are used for reading e-mail after the processing. There is no solution that I'm aware of that combines both into one, let alone something that is simple to use. SMTP (the email protocol) has its own subset of knowledge, much like many other server related technology specializations.